# Underline syntax with react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I'm currently running into a problem that I can't solve (I've been searching for solutions since this morning, but I can't manage to find what I need).

I created a React app using `react-markdown`, allowing the user to edit some post-its, whose content is stored in Markdown format in my DB. But the thing is, I discovered there was no way to underline a text (I thought that if you could do it on Discord, then it means that it's the same in Markdown).

What I'd like is a solution allowing me to simply transform this:

```
**Bold text**
__Underlined text__
```

Into... well... you know what I mean. It doesn't have to be this exact syntax, but at least something similar. The only thing I've found is to create custom components, which I don't want because it requires using an already existing syntax, or, to convert the Markdown with replace() functions and use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to display it, which I don't want either, because isn't it called "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" for a reason?

I'd really appreciate if someone could help. And by the way, sorry for any grammar mistakes, English isn't my native language...

Answer (score 1):

Right now there are no identifiers for `underlining text` in markdown syntax.
But as you know we can achieve it by using `html tags` in our markdown.

But we don't have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in react-markdown for parsing HTML tags. [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) (Check **Appendix A: HTML in markdown**) uses a plugin [rehype-raw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rehype-raw).

You can question the thing that `rehype-raw` internally implements `allowDangerousHtml:true`, but to prevent this , we can wrap our markdown content around [Dompurify.sanitize()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-dompurify) to reduce code vulnerablity.

I also faced the same problem , so this is the approach I tried and it worked for me .

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";
import DOMpurify from 'dompurify';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
   const markdown = `
               **Parsing html in react markdown**

               <u>underlined text</u>
              `;

      return (
           <div className="App">
               <ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}>
                    {DOMpurify.sanitize(markdown)}
              </ReactMarkdown>
           </div>
       );
}
```

[CodeSandBoxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/parsing-html-using-react-markdown-9d4huy?file=/src/App.tsx:0-431)

Comment: adding rehypeRaw indeed fixed the issue, thanks !